# Is overriding a property's type in a Python sub-class pythonic?

Tags: python, oop

I have a python class (P) with a property x, which I use to store a single value in code that instantiates instances of P. Then, in a sub-class of class P (Q) I override (correct nomenclature?) x to instead store a list of values. This feels like just a case of making use of Python's dynamic typing. But is this Pythonic?

```
class P:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

class Q(P):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = [x]


>>> p = P(1)
>>> p.x
1
>>> q = Q(1)
>>> q.x
[1]
>>>
```

Comment: Depends on context, but it's very likely to break Liskov substitutability.

Comment: It is a bit un-Pythonic in that it breaks the idea of least-surprise.  Q inherits from P.  If `P.x` is not a list, it would be surprising to a user that `Q.x` is.

Comment: Just to provide a little context for my specific case: class P contains no methods that rely on x being of a specific type. A separate class X, performs operations on instances of P and relies on x being a single value. Class X would and could never use an instance of class Q instead.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that using this approach isn't so Pythonic in that it breaks Liskov substitutability and the idea of least-surprise.